# Что значит  "расшарить" папку на Ubuntu?

Tags: настройки, ubuntu

Что значит  "расшарить" папку на Ubuntu?

Comment: Да, потому что "папок" в Ubuntu,нет)

Comment: Да что ты говоришь! т.е. папок там нет? Каталог и папка - одно и тоже.

Comment: Папка - на столе у тебя лежит, в которой должен быть мануал по линуксам, в котором написано что такое каталог и директория

Comment: Да, ладно? ты любитель придираться к мелочам? Вопрос, кстати, задан корректно.Ты реально в жизни говоришь "директория" вместо "папка"? а как быстро получается разговаривать с запасом таких длинных слов?

Comment: А ты наверное из тех кто системный блок, процессором называешь?! Зато смотри какая экономия буковок. Коллега, раз уж мы на тех форуме, давайте общаться соответственно.

Answer (score 4):

От англ. «share» — делиться, т.е. позволить другим пользователям получить доступ (чаще с помощью сети) к ресурсам, хранящимся в папке, которую «расшаривают».

Comment: Спасибо Роману эа ответ! Я почти понял.Будет оказия-у кого-нибудь пошарю....попробую.... И , пожалуйста. не ссорьтесь по мелочам...это как-т не солидно...Ведь мы на тех форуме находимся , а не в пивнушке.....жалко нет смайликов, чтобы правильно передать смысловой оттенок!!!Еще раз спасибо! И еще.......в дальнейшем у меня будет много вопросов. Буду очень признателен если мне как "чайнику" ответят продвинутые ученые мужи.... С уважением Радион.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит делать папку общедоступной. Это слово применимо не только к Ubuntu но и к другим ОС и программам файлообменникам  (AMule, DC++). Так же, ты можешь дать права на редактирование содержимого файлов которые лежат в общедоступной папке.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение. Приятно иметь дело с грамотным человеком...   И все-таки....кто подскажет: почему Windous не "видит"  второой жд с установленной Ubuntu???

Comment: Всё просто на самом деле. Linux становится прямым конкурентом Windows. Отсюда и вытекающее последствие. Зачем MS тратить деньги на программистов, которые напишут\портируют драйвер для ext2\3\4? Ведь это позволит вам комфортно жить с 2 ОС и Windows в качестве главной.Но политика MS на данный момент - монополия и ничего другого!

Answer (score 0):

Открыть доступ по локальной сети. И не на Ubuntu, а на Linux.